# programing vb.net, Textbox in second form will not update

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I am trying to create a timer that will countdown from the specified time.

The user enters a time and clicks a button.
The button click opens a second form that has a timer in it.
Every time the timer ticks, the time decreases and the time left is displayed in a *textbox* on form2 (`textbox.text = timeLeft`).

However, the *textbox* will never actually update. It remains blank, and the only time that assigning a new value to the `.text` property will actually work is if I raise an event (for example clicking a button that will change the `.text` property of the *textbox*)

*Here is the code for the timer class

```
Public Class CountdownTimer

Private timeAtStart As Integer
Private timeLeft As Integer

Public Sub StartTimer(ByVal time As Integer)
    timeAtStart = time
    timeLeft = timeAtStart
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub


Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    If timeLeft > 0 Then
        timeLeft = timeLeft - 1
        txtTimeLeft.Text = timeLeft.ToString

    Else
        Timer1.Stop()
        txtTimeRemaining.Text = "Time!"
        txtTimeRemaining.ForeColor = Color.Red
    End If

End Sub

End Class
```

- And here is how I call it:

  ```
  Dim timer As New CountdownTimer
  timer.Show()
  CountdownTimer.StartTimer(CInt(txtSetTime.Text))
  ```

Comment: Put code that you've used please.

Comment: Without seeing the code, my guess is that you need to update the textbox on the Tick event

Comment: set a breakpoint in the tick event...I bet it is never called...is `CountdownTimer` a class or a form?  where is Timer1? is it on a form?  whatever these things are, your last part (how I call it) is wrong.

Comment: CountDown timer is the second form. It is the form that is supposed to display the time. Timer1 is a timer on CountdownTimer.

Comment: There is no TIMER in your CountDownTimer Class

Comment: What do you mean there is no timer? Yes there is, it's on the form and it's called Timer1. If I put a msgbox inside the timer tick event, it shows up at the correct times. But the textbox just isn't updated. I can even get the countdown time to show up on form1, just not on form 2, where the timer is.

Comment: because it is a FORM timer, not a timer **IN** your countdown class!  There is no real reason for that class the way it is written, just make `StartTimer` a procedure because it will only work with one form.  The part that **seems** to work is a tick event on the FORM, not the one in the CLASS - that timer event never fires. (set a break and see)

Comment: I don't understand what I should change. Isn't StartTimer already a procedure? I thought that I need a separate class to go with the countdownTimer form, no?

Comment: `timer.Show()` makes me think your CountDownTimer is actually a form class ... change `CountdownTimer.StartTimer(CInt(txtSetTime.Text))` to  `timer.StartTimer(CInt(txtSetTime.Text))` and the form will work

Comment: @MattWilko I am pretty sure that is a form not a class...the description throws us off...at least it is sort of being used like a form with `timer.Show()`

Comment: @Plutonix - yes your right I just realised that (!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is calling the (form) class not the instance, and I cant see where Timer1 is properly referenced for an independant reusable class.  Here is one way to implement a CountDown class that will work with other forms....

```
 Friend Class CountdownTimer

    Private timeAtStart As Integer
    Private timeLeft As Integer
    Private WithEvents Timer1 As New Timer
    Private txtTimeLeft as TextBox

   Public Sub New(TargetTB as TextBox)
       txtTimeLeft= TargetTB
   End Sub


   Public Sub StartTimer(ByVal time As Integer, timeLength as Integer) 
        timeAtStart = time
        timeLeft = timeLength 

        Timer1.Enabled = True
   End Sub


   Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)_
            Handles Timer1.Tick

       ' just dislaying time left
       If timeLeft > 0 Then
             timeLeft = timeLeft - 1
             txtTimeLeft.Text = timeLeft.ToString

       Else
           Timer1.Stop()
           txtTimeLeft.Text = "Time!"
           txtTimeLeft.ForeColor = Color.Red
      End If

   End Sub

End Class
```

How to use it:

```
Dim CountDn As New CountdownTimer(frm.TextBoxToUse)

' use the INSTANCE name not the class name!!!!
'CountdownTimer.StartTimer(CInt(txtSetTime.Text))
CountDn.StartTimer(CInt(txtSetTime.Text))
```

Answer (score 0):

If it displays the result after the timer has completed, i think you should use the

```
Application.DoEvents()
```

method to see the update immediately. It actually works with Windows Forms. What have you tried, so i can help further

Comment: I tried doing that, I also tried me.refresh, txtTimeRemaining.refresh, and me.show.  None of these worked.

Comment: Use of DoEvents in VB.NET is discouraged, so I wouldn't recommend this. Better to refresh the object that is changing with `.Refresh` if that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You do realize that when you are counting down you are setting a different textbox than when it is complete, right?

```
txtTimeLeft.Text
```

VS

```
txtTimeRemaining.Text
```

Note: Timers run on the same thread as the UI so if you computer (or program) gets busy, the timer will NOT tick at exact intervals.  If you are worried about small variances in your timer, you should compare the difference of your computer time during each tick event to determine how much time had passed.

```
Dim TS = TimeSpan = Now.Subtract(StartingTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try refreshing the text boxes after each update:

So after

```
txtTimeLeft.Text = timeLeft.ToString
```

Add

```
txtTimeLeft.Refresh
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem:

```
Dim timer As New CountdownTimer
timer.Show()
CountdownTimer.StartTimer(CInt(txtSetTime.Text))
```

You instantiate a new object called `timer`, but then start the timer on the `CountdownTimer` object

You need to change your code to this:

```
Dim timer As New CountdownTimer
timer.Show()
timer.StartTimer(CInt(txtSetTime.Text))
```

Comment: Well, the other part of the original problem (I think) is that one (or more) of the TBs are on a different form, so in the tick event, <frm2Name.> would need to be added.